# Which model to use for multiclass audio classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I am working on a project wherein I want to classify Tabla taalas(patterns) and I didn't find any dataset regarding it. I am recording them myself and I've ~500 data samples recorded. What model shall I use to classify the patterns if I have less than 500 samples and 6 classes?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about these Tabla taalas? Is it music or speech content, or something else? How long is a typical sound that you want to classify?

Comment: @jonnor Tabla taalas are reoccuring patterns like drum loops and are a music i.e rhythmic content and I want to classify them. The duration, however, isn't fixed and changes according to each taala(pattern) and with the tempo.

Comment: From my knowledge , i would say to try model out there. There are no fixed model. Try and see which works for you. For multiclass problem it would be good idea to use use categorical cross entropy in your last layer.

Answer (score 1):

500 samples for 6 classes is not so much. You should put aside about 100 samples for validation and 100 for testing, leaving 300 samples for training.
I'm assuming that these drum loop are on the order of 1 second long (0.5-5 seconds). Then I would recommend trying a pretrained audio model, which typically have 1 second analysis windows. For example [OpenL3](https://pypi.org/project/openl3/), which is a powerful and easy to use audio embedding. It even has pretrained versions trained on audio.
On top of the audio embeddings try a simple linear classifier like LogisticRegression or a RandomForest.